# Symfony 2: problem with passwords encryption

Tags: symfony

I made a simple registration form with form builder. It seems I did everything totally like in the documentation and articles but I still can't make passwords to store in database not in a plain text.

Here are some files, please, help me.

security.yml: http://pastebin.com/4FwBaZQK
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User: http://pastebin.com/iUGd4Cz1
Acme\SecurityBundke\Controller\SecurityController: http://pastebin.com/wTVy2zE2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [encoding user passwords](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password).

The code snippet from the documentation should be applied to the user object after it's bound, but before it's persisted and flushed (so between lines 45 and 46 in your Security controller):

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$user = new Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User();

$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($password);
```

Comment: I suppose you could implement a Doctrine event listener to do this behind the scenes before an entity is persisted.

Comment: I created a [short gist](https://gist.github.com/1222436) that you can use as a service to preserve separation of concerns. You could even extend it a little bit to take the user as a reference and modify the password inline, if you wanted to streamline the process in your controller.

Comment: Thank you! Will try to obtain the factory in the controller and pass to `setPassword` as optional parameter.

Comment: Where will the salt come from? $user->getSalt() will just return an empty string the first time for me